# ref struct declaration in ref class

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am stuck in a code with lot of errors. I am working on a ref class, in which I have declare a struct, I came to know, that I am not allowed to use the usual struct, it has to be a ref struct. but still I get strange error:

> error C3816: 'namespace::className::structName' was previouslydeclared
>   or defined with a different managed modifier

code example:

```
ref class someclass{

    ref struct somestruct{
        char a1;
        char a2;
    };
    //my decleration.
    array<struct somestruct>^ variable = gcnew array<struct somestruct>(5);
};
```

Is it correct?
if not, please help me...

Comment: post the actual code with the actual error message. This error doesn't apply to this code

Comment: Well, I am getting error for this code....

Comment: Nope, you're not. Where is `namespace::className::structName defined`? Anyway, I fixed the compile issue in my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to fix it:

```
ref class someclass{

    ref struct somestruct{
        char a1;
        char a2;
    };
    array<somestruct^>^ variable;

    someclass() : variable(gcnew array<somestruct^>(5))
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are battling basic syntax here.  The distinction between value types and reference types is a very important one in managed code.  You declared a `ref struct`, that requires that you use the hat in the array declaration.  It is also *very* likely that you don't want a ref struct here.  They act *exactly* like classes and get allocated on the heap.  Simple structures like this should be a *value struct* instead, the closest equivalent to a C or C++ struct.

Don't use the *struct* keyword in the array declaration, that's C syntax.  Last problem is that you can't initialize a member like that, only the C# compiler supports that.  Which implements it by moving the code into the constructor.  In C++/CLI you have to do this yourself.  So the likely syntax you want here is:

```
public ref class someclass {
private:
    value struct somestruct{
        char a1;
        char a2;
    };
    array<somestruct>^ variable;
public:
    someclass() {
        variable = gcnew array<somestruct>(5);
        //todo: initialize array members
    }
};
```

Guessing at what should be private vs public.

Comment: Probably better to use a *ctor-initializer*, like sehe's answer.  But **`value struct`** is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that you forgot `ref` before `struct`.
Since it's not C, you don't need to prepend type name with `struct`. Just use `array<somestruct^>^`.
(But `array<ref struct somestruct^>^` works too)

Comment: Nop, it didnt work with that either... Conceptually, am I right to do this operation?

Comment: @Jasim Khan Afridi : it can not to work because of error C3845, but you asked about error C3816.